# Windows 8 Metro cryptography - using SignedCms Pkcs7

Tags: c#, windows-8, cryptography, windows-runtime

`SignedCms` is not supported in Windows 8 Metro. Is there an equivalent/replacement for it in WinRT?

Sample of the code i need to convert to Metro below:

```
message.Data = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toDigest)), true);
message.Data.Decode(part.BinaryContent);
```

Comment: Other than writing your own implementation, you can use our SecureBlackbox .NET edition (http://www.eldos.com/sbb/), it has Windows RT assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i was looking for here:

http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/11/encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-winrt-2/