# Is there an alternative of SignedCMS in WinRT?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, asn.1

And again I ran into trouble while porting a .NET Desktop App to a Windows Store App...
Long story short, I have a ZIP File with an encrypted and signed XML File and a certificate in it. The decryption is working (more or less) but now I have to "unsign" the XML and I'm stuck.

In the .NET App the unsigning is done with System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms but that class does not exist in WinRt (as always...)

Is there any alternative in WinRT?

here is some of the code used in the .NET App:

```
public static byte[] CheckAndRemoveSignature(byte[] data,  X509Certificate2Collection certStore, out SignedCms out_signature)
    {
        SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms();
        signedMessage.Decode(data);

        if ((certStore != null) && (certStore.Count > 0))
            signedMessage.CheckSignature(certStore, true);
        else
            signedMessage.CheckSignature(true);

        out_signature = signedMessage;

        // return data without signature
        return signedMessage.ContentInfo.Content;
    }
```

I already searched a lot, but the only thing I found, that could have helped me was this post. Unfortunately the marked answer does not provide any helpful information :(

[Windows 8 Metro cryptography - using SignedCms Pkcs7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272579/windows-8-metro-cryptography-using-signedcms-pkcs7)

I would really appreciate some help here :)

---

### Edit

The essential problem is to get the original xml data out of the signed byte array.
Or, more specifically I need the functionality of these few lines of code in WinRT

```
SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms();
signedMessage.Decode(data);
byte[] result = signedMessage.ContentInfo.Content;
```

I tried the example from pepo, but I get a MalformedContent Exception

```
private byte[] CheckAndRemoveSignature(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            // load using bouncyCastle
            CmsSignedData sig = new CmsSignedData(data);
            // var allSigsValid = VerifySignatures(sig);
            byte[] content = sig.SignedContent.GetContent() as byte[];
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cryptOutput.Text += "Error removing Signature: " + ex;
            return data;
        }
```

I get this exception:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException: Malformed content. ---> System.ArgumentException: unknown object in factory: DerApplicationSpecific
at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.ContentInfo.GetInstance(Object obj)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsUtilities.ReadContentInfo(Asn1InputStream aIn)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsUtilities.ReadContentInfo(Asn1InputStream aIn)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsUtilities.ReadContentInfo(Stream input)
at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsSignedData..ctor(Byte[] sigBlock)
at TestApp.MainPage.CheckAndRemoveSignature(Byte[] data)
```

---

Code from Desktop App where the XML-File is signed:

```
  private byte[] signInternal(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 signatureCert, bool signatureOnly)
    {
        CAPICOM.SignedData signedData = new CAPICOM.SignedDataClass();
        CAPICOM.Utilities u = new CAPICOM.UtilitiesClass();
        signedData.set_Content(u.ByteArrayToBinaryString(data));
        GC.Collect();

        CAPICOM.Signer signer = new CAPICOM.Signer();
        signer.Options = CAPICOM.CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_OPTION.CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_END_ENTITY_ONLY;

        CAPICOM.CertificateClass certClass = new CAPICOM.CertificateClass();
        certClass.Import(Convert.ToBase64String(signatureCert.Export(X509ContentType.SerializedCert)));
        signer.Certificate = certClass;

        GC.Collect();

        if (this.validateCert(signatureCert))
            return (byte[])Convert.FromBase64String(signedData.Sign(signer, signatureOnly, CAPICOM.CAPICOM_ENCODING_TYPE.CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64));
        else
            return new byte[] { };
    }
```

---

### Solution

In the end it turned out that there was a big problem with encoding, that I did not think was noteworthy. The answer from pepo is working, however I will post my version, to show how it works if you get the file from a zip folder:

```
// get bytes from zip
byte[] data = getFileContentAsByteArray(zipBytes, ze.FileName);
var dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);

// check and remove signature
bool isValid;
byte[] withoutSig = CheckAndRemoveSignature(dataString, out isValid);
```

```
    private byte[] CheckAndRemoveSignature(string data, out bool isValid)
    {
        isValid = false;

        // using bouncyCastle
        try
        {
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            // assign data to CmsSignedData                  
            CmsSignedData sig = new CmsSignedData(bytes);

            // check if signature is valid
            var allSigsValid = VerifySignaturesBC(sig);
            if (allSigsValid.Equals(true)) { isValid = true; }

            // get signature from cms
            byte[] content = sig.SignedContent.GetContent() as byte[];

            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { cryptOutput.Text += "Error in 'BouncyCastle unsign' " + ex; return null; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need SignedCMS? Do you have xmldsig or CMS (PKCS#7)?

Comment: As I said, I am porting an existing App and there, SignedCMS.ContentInfo.Content was used to get the .xml out of the ZIP File - I assumed I need that in WinRT too, because when I only decrypt the , it doesn't work.

Comment: So you have 2 options then. Use c# version of bouncycastle or manually parse out the xml using some ASN.1 library.

Comment: is there no way to do this with the standard WinRT API? Well done Microsoft... But thanks anyway for your reply :)

Comment: Well, you can use LINQ to XML to make parsing the XML incredibly easy.

Comment: thanks Nate, I will consider that :) But there is still the problem, that I have to get the Content out of my signedCMS so that I can serialize it. I need the data without the signature...

Comment: pepo, can you give me more detail on how exactly I can get the content of my CMS with bouncycastle? or maybe a suggestion which ASN.1 library would be best to use here?

Comment: I will write it as an answer because the code is little long.

Comment: Could you use `CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY` encoding type in Sign method when using capicom? Lets see if the output will be the same.

Comment: I can try it for now, but in the end I cannot change the existing code of the desktop app because that part is already in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments I understand that you have a PKCS#7 structure (SignedCms) and the content of that structure is XmlDocument.

Because there is no SignedCms in WinRT API you have two choices. Either use some ASN.1 library and parse PKCS#7 manually looking for content or use i.e. BouncyCastle which has SignedCms implemented and can parse that strusture. 
You asked for an example using bouncyCastle. Here it is.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store;
using System.Collections;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // make some pkcs7 signedCms to work on
            SignedCms p7 = new SignedCms(new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 }));
            p7.ComputeSignature(new CmsSigner(), false);

            // encode to get signedCms byte[] representation
            var signedCms = p7.Encode();

            // load using bouncyCastle
            CmsSignedData sig = new CmsSignedData(signedCms);

            var allSigsValid = VerifySignatures(sig);

            byte[] content = sig.SignedContent.GetContent() as byte[];
        }

        // taken from bouncy castle SignedDataTest.cs
        private static bool VerifySignatures(
            CmsSignedData sp)
        {
            var signaturesValid = true;
            IX509Store x509Certs = sp.GetCertificates("Collection");
            SignerInformationStore signers = sp.GetSignerInfos();

            foreach (SignerInformation signer in signers.GetSigners())
            {
                ICollection certCollection = x509Certs.GetMatches(signer.SignerID);

                IEnumerator certEnum = certCollection.GetEnumerator();
                certEnum.MoveNext();
                Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)certEnum.Current;

                signaturesValid &= signer.Verify(cert);
            }
            return signaturesValid;
        }
    }
}
```

As for the ASN.1 library, I have only worked with bouncyCastle which has ASN.1 parser or [ASN.1 editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) which is a very useful GUI application for showing structure of PKCS#7, certificates etc. So I can recommend only those two.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I always get an exception when I want to load my byte-array into CmsSignedData...
`Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException: Malformed content. ---> System.ArgumentException: unknown object in factory: `

Comment: Could you send this signedCms or does it have some sensitive data?

Comment: unfortunately it does have sensitive data :( but I can try to find the part of code in the Desktop App where the xml is signed

Comment: OK, dump this SignedCms to file (in binary format) and try to open it with ASN.1 editor. Could you paste a screenshot? It should be safe if there will be everything up to this oid 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1. This oid means data and this data should be in the next row (I don't need the data, only the upper rows).

Comment: when I open it in the ASN.1 editor it just shows me one line: 
`(0,73) Application (13) : '4D424133....'`

the content of the SignedCms when I convert it to a Base64String starts like this: "MIMBA3AGC..."

I guess CAPICOM signs the data somewhat special, so other ASN.1 decoding methods don't work? Could that be the case?

Comment: I don't think so. Something is wrong with this data. Did you save it in binary format or base64?

Comment: I saved it as binary, as base64 string and just like it comes out of the zip and with different file extensions - there are always the same numbers in it.. However, when I debug the DesktopApp there is extactly this string which then is converted to byte array and sent into that method I wrote in the start post

Comment: I managed to write a test-application which creates a dummy zip in the exact same way the original desktop app does. maybe I could now send the signedCMS to you and you could take a look at it? @pepo

Comment: OK, you could use [github gist](https://gist.github.com/) to upload the code and send me a link.

Comment: Sorry, I had little time these past days. I tried to compile the code but had some trouble with it. I also installed Capicom but I might be missing something. Could you run the code and use p12 from [here](https://gist.github.com/peponeska/b3afbe37dc27d676a429) ? Please upload the result to your gist and I will look at it. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, thanks for trying nonetheless :) here is the signed xml file: https://gist.github.com/katho2404/b9c6ea41199abe33f507

Comment: It works flawlessly with the code from my answer. I have updated [my gist](https://gist.github.com/peponeska/b3afbe37dc27d676a429). Try it. Does it work for you?

Comment: wow, that's unexpected, but I will try it, for sure! on the other hand - if it really does work now, what does that mean for my application? that the certificate used for signing isn't valid?

Comment: Hm, I did not try it in windows store app, just console app. But I do not understand why it should not work. What exception do you get. And on what line of code?

Comment: I don't get an exception, it just returns some gibberish string (but with other characters than the original signed file)

Comment: Where does it return a string? In the example I posted there is a byte[] content variable. I tried to call `var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);` and it was ok (well, one character was not - `Goethestra�e`).

Comment: with string I simply meant the text, sorry ;-) finally, after a lot of trial and error testing I got it working in the original project. It seems to make a big difference where and how I convert and encode the data - whatever the reason. In the end your sample code did help me a lot, it was "just" the encoding problems that kept me busy. Anyhow, a big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You’re probably looking for something like Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CmsAttachedSignature.VerifySignature() and it's 'Content' property
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.cmsattachedsignature.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I already tried that and I get an exception: "ASN1 bad tag value met." ... :(