# SignedCms alternative in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Does an alternative to System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms class exist in .NET Core? Or do I have to dig into BouncyCastle, like they do in WinRT case? [Is there an alternative of SignedCMS in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658501/is-there-an-alternative-of-signedcms-in-winrt)

Comment: Brace yourself for the BouncyCastle experience my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent to SignedCms in .NET Core at this time.

You're quite welcome to create an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues to indicate that it's a type that you would like to be brought over.

Comment: Thanks, created an issue there.

Answer (score 6):

FYI in case it helps. It seems that support for SignedCms and other essential .NET classes for S/MIME are available via this `NUGET` package:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs
```

I.e. before I added this `NUGET` package to my Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) .NET Core project, I received these compilation errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CmsRecipientCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'X509IssuerSerial' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EnvelopedCms' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SignedCms' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SignerInfoCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ContentInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CmsRecipient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RecipientInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS0103  The name 'SubjectIdentifierType' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SignerInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SignerInfoCollection' because 'SignerInfoCollection' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CmsSigner' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

After I added the `NUGET` package, I could compile successfully.

Comment: Yeah, they added it to .NET Core Platform Extensions some time ago. Already using it for a while.